# Python, how to enable all warnings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, warnings

I was setting up a ImportWarning as seemed appropriate but noticed this warning is not reported by default;

How can I set python to report ImportWarning or all warnings?

Here is the import warning i wrote:

```
try:
    from markdown import markdown

except ImportError, err:
    warnings.warn(
        'Unable to load Pypi package `markdown`, HTML output will be unavailable. {}'.format(err),
        ImportWarning
    )
```

Comment: @rpattiso Ahh, I was using a shebang line to run my script, running with the python interpreter and the W flag did make the warning appear!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('module')
```

Or:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('always')
```

The list of filters are in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)

Answer (score 23):

To enable warnings run python with the `-Wdefault` or `-Wd` switch.

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable warnings for just one section of code:

```py
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('always')
    # all warnings here are enabled
# warnings here are left as default (probably silent)
```